# Javascript Algorithm Understanding

Tags: javascript, variables

Okay so I know what the code is doing overall. I understand why the output is the output that I get. But for the life of me I can't figure out the exact steps the javascript code makes the browser take to arrive at the final output. How does this code make the browser know after adding one plus two and getting three that it should add three plus two next instead of three plus three? Basically I was trying to figure out step by step how the browser uses this code when it is given this code to use. I finally realized due to the answers below that I was just over thinking this as it is actually really simple. Two is added to One Getting Three. A is Changed to 2 B is changed to Three. Three is then added to two getting five. A is changed to Three B is Changed to Five. While this is happening if C ends up being even it is saved in the variable sum. This keeps happening until 4000000.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var sum = 0;

while ( a < 4000000) {

    if(a % 2 === 0) {

        sum += a;

    }

    c = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = c;



 }

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a=b` sets the value of variable a to the value of variable b. `b=c` sets the value of variable b to the value of variable c.

This persists throughout the loop. When the while restarts, a,b and c keep the values you just set them as.

Comment: You seem to have understood my post the best. I wanted to know the exact steps. Your answer really helped me figure these out.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` do not equal the same number. In the first iteration:

```
c = a + b // 1 + 2
a = b // 2
b = c // 3
```

what don't you understand?

Comment: Basically what I think is happening is that 1 is being added to 2 resulting in 3 of course and that b is now three due to b = c which then causes a = b. After that a is added to the sum if it is an even number

Comment: Numbers are primitives, so when you set `a = b`, you are setting `a` to the _value_ of `b`.

Comment: I really didn't understand the steps that were being taken correctly. Thank you for your post as seeing the numbers beside the variables helped me realize that I was just over complicating things and second guessing myself.